# incompatible pointer types assigning to nsarray from nsdictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsarray, plist

I'm new to iPhone development and have had great success with with answers from here so I am hoping to receive help directly.  I am reading data into a tableview from a plist.  The application works fine but I get 2 warnings when I compile.  I know why I get the errors but I have been unsuccessful with resolving the issues.  Although this app works I really would like to resolve the warnings efficiently.  When I tried changing the NSDictionary to NSArray the warning goes away but the table is no longer populated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Staff and Data are defined as NSArray in the Delegate .h file.  The warnings show in the delegate .m file below.

My Delegate has the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window

NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
NSString *SPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *StaffPath = [SPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Staff.plist"];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
**self.data = tempDict;**
[tempDict release];


    NSDictionary *staffDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:StaffPath];
    **self.staff = staffDict;**  
    [staffDict release];
```

In my staff ViewController I have the following:

```
    if(CurrentLevel == 0) {

        //Initialize our table data source
        NSArray *staffDict = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        self.tableDataSource = staffDict;
        [staffDict release];


        Midwest_DigestiveAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (Midwest_DigestiveAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.staff valueForKey:@"Rows"];     
}
else 
    self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle;
```

Comment: did you solve this? @Corey Brown I am encountering the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your code suggests that the staff and data properties are NSDictionary instances. You initialize them to dictionary objects and you reference them as dictionary objects. Why then are you declaring them as NSArray objects?

You should change how they are declared so they are NSDictionary in your header file rather than NSArray. That seems to me the most logical way to remove your warnings.

This should still work assuming the contents of your "staff" NSDictionary has a key named "Rows" whose value is an NSArray. The code you have to initialize self.tableDataSource with an  empty NSArray seems redundant, as you immediately overwrite the value with the

```
self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.staff valueForKey:@"Rows"];
```

line in your code

Comment: Thank You Very Much.  I tried this,before, and the table came back empty however this time it worked.

Answer (score 1):

An `NSArray` holds a one dimensional list of items where an `NSDictionary` maps keys to values.

> Array:
>
> [a, b, c]
>
> Dictionary:
>
> {@"a" = @"first item", @"b" = @"second item"}

Could you declare data as `NSDictionary *data;` and populate it as `data = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];`

You then access values in the dictionary with `[data valueForKey:@"key"]`